# Is it okay to use Rails 3.1 for a new project? Is hard to convert over?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version, upgrade, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have just started using 3.0.7. I am about 2 weeks of development in.

I was wondering if I should keep building for 3.0.7 or switch to 3.1 before I have too much code to port over? I like most of the new features (my only fear is not having good error messages when I use coffeescript), so I'd like to code towards the latest and greatest if it's relatively safe.

The javascript standards look interesting, and the attr_accessible fix sounds like it's very much appreciated.

Is Rails 3.1 compatible with all the gems out there though?

Also, if I go the 3.1 route, is hard or easy to migrate my project towards it? How might one go about that?

I guess this is a lot of mini yet related questions. I'd really appreciate some answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you want to ride on Rails 3.1 you should do it :). As for me I have some projects on Rails 2.3.5, 3.0.5 and would like to port them on Rails 3.1 but there is to much code there :). So don't be afraid and go to the fresh stuff (unless your code overflow :) ).
Rails 3.1 are pretty stable for now (I didn't have much problems with installing and using it)

Comment: Hi Boris. How should I go about doing it? - Create a new project and start copying files over? Or is there a command I can run?

Comment: @Fire Just run all your tests to figure out where the code should be edited. That was how I did it.

Comment: What about directory paths and configuration settings? This will just work?

Comment: For better work you need to create completely new project and copy your code there, because thre are a lot of stuff that connat be upgraded.

Comment: I think I got everything to work. I just have to organize my javascripts directory now since the vendor/lib/app is very different and they no longer load. I don't think I need require.js anymore either

Answer (score 3):

If you're only two weeks into a project then it makes sense to stay on the edge and move to 3.1.

The way I'd do it is clone my project to a new dir (you're using git / similar version control, right?), change the Rails version in my Gemspec, run tests and play around to see what got broken (if anything). Based on the results you can figure out whether the effort is too great.

Regarding gem compatibility, hardly anything is compatible with *all* gems out there. Since you're two weeks in, you probably know which gems you use. Test like I suggested and you'll have an idea whether it's compatible with what you need. If you're using popular gems, then they'll most likely be updated to work with 3.1 soon enough.